# Detect, if ScrollBar of ScrollViewer is visible or not

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollviewer

I have a TreeView. Now, I want to detect, if the vertical Scrollbar is visible or not.
When I try it with

```
var visibility = this.ProjectTree.GetValue(ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibilityProperty)
```

(where this.ProjectTree is the TreeView)
I get always Auto for visibility.

How can I do this to detect, if the ScrollBar is effectiv visible or not?

Thanks.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need to do this?  In most cases where I've seen someone doing this, it was a sub-optimal way of solving some other problem.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use the `ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility` property. But for that, you first need to find the `ScrollViewer` in the `TreeView`'s template. To do that, you can use the following extension method:

```
    public static IEnumerable<DependencyObject> GetDescendants(this DependencyObject obj)
    {
        foreach (var child in obj.GetChildren())
        {
            yield return child;
            foreach (var descendant in child.GetDescendants())
            {
                yield return descendant;
            }
        }
    }
```

Use it like this:

```
var scrollViewer = ProjectTree.GetDescendants().OfType<ScrollViewer>().First();
var visibility = scrollViewer.ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility;
```

Comment: Can you attach a property changed event to this property?

Comment: @malthe, I don't think there's a specific event for this, but since it's a dependency property, you can always watch it using `DependencyPropertyDescriptor.AddValueChanged`

Comment: Note that if you're trying to use ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility on a Scrollviewer then make sure VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" in xaml

Answer (score 3):

ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility instead of VerticalScrollBarVisibility

VerticalScrollBarVisibility sets or gets the *behavior*, whereas the ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility gives you the actual status.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.computedverticalscrollbarvisibility(v=vs.110).aspx

You cannot access this property the same way you did in your code example, see Thomas Levesque's answer for that :)

Comment: Yes, but it's a property of the ScrollViewer, not the TreeView, so you need to find the ScrollViewer in the template first.

Comment: I assumed that if the code in the OP returned a result, then it successfully addressed the ScrollViewer allready, just the wrong property...

Comment: No, because ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility is an attached property, which is set on the TreeView, not the ScrollViewer.

Answer (score 3):

Easiest approach I've found is to simply subscribe to the `ScrollChanged` event which is part of the attached property `ScrollViewer`, for example:

```
<TreeView ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged="TreeView_OnScrollChanged">
</TreeView>
```

Codebehind:

```
private void TreeView_OnScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.OriginalSource is ScrollViewer sv)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(sv.ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility);
    }
}
```

For some reason IntelliSense didn't show me the event but it works.