# Detect when scrollbar is visible in UWP

Tags: uwp, uwp-scrollviewer

With a `ScrollViewer` in UWP, I need to detect when the scrollbar or the panning indicator is visible so that I can add padding to the ScrollViewer so that the scrollbar when it is visible does not overlap content within the viewer.

This response on SO to [Detect, if ScrollBar of ScrollViewer is visible or not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20048605/1690217) looked promising, however it is written for WPF. It did direct me towards the `ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility` property that also exists in the *UWP* `ScrollViewer` however this always has the value of `Visible`, even when the scrollbar is hidden in the user interface.

XAML fragment:

```xml
<ScrollViewer
    Name="ForegroundElement"
    VerticalScrollMode="Auto">
    <Grid>
        <Frame x:Name="shellFrame" />
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

The documentation for `ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility` suggests that this is the most appropriate property to determine if the scrollbar is visible, the `VerticalScrollBarVisibility` property on the otherhand is used to indicate if you want the vertical scrollbar to be available at all.

> **[ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.computedverticalscrollbarvisibility?view=netcore-3.1)**
>   A Visibility that indicates whether the vertical scroll bar is visible. The default is Visible.
>
> > *that last bit is confusing, it looks as if this property always stays in the default state.*

Initially I tried to register a change handler for the `ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibilityProperty` in code behind, which as a concept generally works well to intercept changes to *dependency properties* on controls that do not expose a specific change event, but the following implementation never registered a change:

```cs
public ShellPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    // register for property change on the scrollbar, add padding to the page
    ForegroundElement.RegisterPropertyChangedCallback(
        ScrollViewer.ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibilityProperty, 
        ForegroundElement_ScrollBarVisibilityChanged);
}


private void ForegroundElement_ScrollBarVisibilityChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyProperty dp)
{
    if (ForegroundElement.ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility == Visibility.Visible)
    {
        if (ForegroundElement.Padding.Right != 18)
            ForegroundElement.Padding = new Thickness(0, 0, 18, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        if (ForegroundElement.Padding.Right != 0)
            ForegroundElement.Padding = new Thickness(0);
    }
}
```

Changing the implementation to listen for the [LayoutUpdated Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.layoutupdated?view=winrt-18362) didn't help a lot because the value of `ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility` was always `Visible`, even when the scrollbar was not visible in the UI.

I double checked that the `VerticalScrollMode` was set to `"Auto"` as I am aware of this being a concern in other platforms, however changing this value or omitting it completely had no affect.

---

#### Background

Whilst the [MS implementation of the scrollbar in modern Windows 10 store apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/scroll-controls) and the Edge Browser is well documented and generally tolerated by the *pro-windows* community because its seen as a feature of the OS, this default behaviour of hiding the scrollbar until the user hovers over it is causing our UWP apps to receive a lot of negative user feedback in the marketplace. The panning indicator is too subtle and our users are confused because they are not aware that a region can be scrolled at all.

> For this post I have focussed specifically on a declared `ScrollViewer`, however the same issues apply to other standard controls that implement `ScrollViewer` internally in their control templates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is another property on a `ScrollViewer` that can be used to determine when the scrollbar will be visible, [ScrollableHeight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.scrollableheight?view=winrt-18362)

> **ScrollViewer.ScrollableHeight Property**
>   Gets a value that represents the vertical size of the area that can be scrolled; the difference between the height of the extent and the height of the viewport.

So when the `ScrollableHeight` is *zero*, then the scrollbar will be `Collapsed`, for all other positive values the scrollbar will `Visible`.

This implementation works as expected:

```cs
public ShellPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    // register for property change on the scrollbar, add padding to the page
    ForegroundElement.RegisterPropertyChangedCallback(
        ScrollViewer.ScrollableHeightProperty, 
        ForegroundElement_ScrollableHeightChanged);
}

private void ForegroundElement_ScrollableHeightChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyProperty dp)
{
    if (ForegroundElement.ScrollableHeight > 0)
    {
        if (ForegroundElement.Padding.Right != 18)
            ForegroundElement.Padding = new Thickness(0, 0, 18, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        if (ForegroundElement.Padding.Right != 0)
            ForegroundElement.Padding = new Thickness(0);
    }
}
```